# Do moderators try to reason with companies with excessive self promotion?

Tags: discussion, spam

I saw a [spam post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639427) ([mirror for <10k](http://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts/by-url?url=//stackoverflow.com/a/36639427)) today that got me thinking about this. Several times in the last month now I've seen that people, obviously affiliated with companies (they don't hide this, they even put their affiliation into their profile or use a clear name that can be traced back to the company via Google), do not at all understand the rules of self promotion on SO. Now I understand that we can comment and alert moderators in these scenarios, but I thought of an alternate approach that moderators (or even users? Maybe not) could take to get these companies to stop wasting both our time destroying their self promotion and their time writing it (the usual spam post gets ~10 views before it is destroyed):

Why don't we send guidance directly to the companies that these individuals are employed by, something to the effect of "We know that you want to promote your product, but here is why you can't do that on SO...". The guidance could be sent via the company's official information channels (email etc).

The idea behind this is to turn companies that currently only waste our and their time away from doing so more effectively than just destroying the accounts they use for this.

What do you think? Is this feasible, and if, even desirable?

Comment: You assume spammers are reasonable people.

Comment: I assume that some companies can be reasoned with, yes. This isn't about the spam bots, its about the humans who do it. cc @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: Maybe, but color me skeptical. I imagine some of these spam postings are made by some sketchy "marketing" companies, and the people hiring them don't really care.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara In the example above, the spam was posted by a webmaster for the company that makes the product. I imagine there must be some way to make him and them see how this doesn't work and puts them into a bad light. This user above has even tried this twice before too, so we know that just spam deleting his posts wont dissuade him.

Comment: The specific post you linked to looks like it's from some long term spammers - way past the point where contact would be useful.

Answer (score 13):

> Why don't we send guidance directly to the companies that these
>   individuals are employed by, something to the effect of "We know that
>   you want to promote your product but here is why you can't do that on
>   SO

We can't do this because :

1. These companies themselves might not be involved. Their employees could be spamming on their own.
2. Some people might try to post **fake** spam and watch while we send mails to companies whose employees weren't actually involved in this spam post(targeting innocent people). There is no way of actually separating *a real spam post from a fake one*.
3. The person posting this spam could be the CEO of his one man company.

Comment: Hmm, #2 is interesting. Spam a competitor's product to paint a negative image or get it blacklisted. I wonder how effective that is.

Comment: But in the event that its a fake spammer, the company could then take action against that. And I suggest this only for individuals where you can reasonably infer (clear name profiles of employees, actual employment data in the public profile) that they work there.

Comment: If I was running a company I would want to know if someone is spamming sites with my product (and I would take legal action against it)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - We cannot rule that out.  And honestly, killing your competition will always be part of any company's *success strategy*

Comment: Im not suggesting we berate the company in question in such a mail, merely inform them. If an employee had been spamming on his own I'd _also_ definately want to know that as a company. I cannot imagine a scenario where such an information mail would be unwelcome.

Comment: @Magisch - Most people on SO don't add real names / employer details / location in their profiles. What if I created a new account with your real name and added that I work for your employer and then posted a spam?. How difficult is it?. Now what can anyone do about this?. Your company might not know your personal email Id and SO doesn't know your official email ID.

Comment: Then I would be able to explain to my company that this wasn't in fact me, and I would be able to take appropiate action to stop this identity theft. I don't see how I could lose on this. Im also proposing this _only_ be done manually and only for crystal clear cases (like the one above)

Comment: @Magisch - And they will believe it?.. They might want to do their own investigation, get legal involved and then find out that this was posted by some 8 year old kid in a country which doesn't care about your company or SO. What will they do?. Even before this, we need an emailId from your company that we can use. And how can we even trust that the person who says that he represents your company is actually from your company?.

Answer (score 6):

What happens to spam depends a lot on context and history. Sometimes there is a reaching out to companies and that can happen via two mechanisms:

1. The standard mod message text does include a link to and quote from the [help centre advice on self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). This gets sent to individuals by mods on a case by case basis, more below.
2. For more extreme cases SE community managers have reached out to broader contacts at companies. This is rare but not unheard of.

Where these two options work best is when the people concerned are well intentioned. Generally CM involvement only makes any sense for larger companies where it's clear that there's a pattern and backstory and it's rare.

Usually it's pretty clear from the spam itself and a few searches of similar deleted posts if the intention is good, or if the person posting simply doesn't care.

It's a pretty safe bet that if you've seen the same spam more than once they've already been explicitly told where to put it and didn't do a great job on taking that hint.

For those who just don't care there's nothing more to be done than destroy the accounts and feeding spam-ram. Sometimes in the most extreme cases a URL blacklist is worth adding, but that's rare.

(For the worst cases it's pretty therapeutic to [drop a heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233651/web-solutions-and-digital-marketing-services-company-sam-digital-media#comment60098036_36233651) [dose of sarcasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605340/identity-theft-protection-1-888-226-1322-how-to-prevent-identity-theft-1-888-2#comment60807757_36605340) after deletion should anyone ever look at the post again though, but that really doesn't achieve anything)